# double click on list row to open view form SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, javascript, css

Normally list items needs title field to open the item in edit/view form.

I was just wondering is there any way to remove the title field and from the view and allow user to click on the row to open the view form.

Comment: There is also a little 'edit' icon that can be used instead of the title field, but that doesn't really answer your question.  I guess you already know about the Quick Edit mode for in-line editing.

Comment: yes there is i made the view removing the title so that the users can double or single click on the row to open the item in view form. This is what i need.

Comment: Did you try Client Side Rendering? I have done styling for entire row in lost view using Client Side Rendering, it should work in your case as well...Here is one of the link for colour coding the  entire row using CSR. See if you can use the same approach in your case..https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/conditionally-highlight-the-rows-of-a-sharepoint-list-view-using-client-side-ren/

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the method below for the issue.

You could modify the view and add the “Edit (link to edit item)” and change the position to “1”.

[image]
And there is the icon in the list view and you can click the icon to open the edit form of the list item. 
After all, you could edit the item even if you hide the title column.

[image]

Comment: yes this is possible. But i would require to have the row clicked and popup with a view only form.